# Is there a way to replace class extension in groovy/java?

Tags: java, groovy

My application is an automation testing framework written in groovy/java. 
Currently I have 2 variants of its usage: 
1) All my tests classes extends from BaseTest class which reads properties, do some other staff like setup and cleanup, but in the main it starts SpringBoot context where the main application to be tested works. It woks perfect, but every time I run any test - spring starting first which is takes up to a minute of my time.
2) I have another class to extend from called ProxyBaseTest class which creates proxy to a running instance of main application (in case I started it manually with gradle in a separate window). It also works good.

The main problem for me is to replace all the time

```
class SomeTestClass extends BaseTest {
```

with

```
class SomeTestClass extends ProxyBaseTest {
```

and vise versa.

Is there a way to do something like that:

class SomeTestClass extends A {
....
}

```
 Class A {
    ....
  if(applicationIsRunning){
    // use/return/extend/replace/??? from ProxyBaseTest
  }else{
    // use/return/extend/replace/??? from BaseTest
  }
}
```

I can't merge BaseTest and ProxyBaseTest because BaseTest using springbeans, spring context, annotations etc... if I'll be able to merge it - it is going to make anyone mad after.

Answer (score 0):

3 different ways to do it. The key words to look for are:

- **Annotations:** Don't subclass from a base test class. Annotate the class instead. E.g. jUnit went from subclassing to annotations.
- **Delegation:** Your base class `A` is an example, where the `use/return/extend/replace/???` is a method call to the class actually doing the work.
- **Composition:** Instead of subclassing from a `Test` class, the code should obtain a reference to the appropriate test class and store it as a field, so you can call whatever method you need. The two test class implementations should then implement a common interface, which is the type of the field.